# Problemas para apagar um objeto "circulo" que está no google-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou tendo problemas para apagar objetos do tipo circulo (API google-maps) que estão sendo mostrados em meu mapa.

Eu possuo uma função que recebede dados JSON e cria um array global (**arrayElementos**) contendo objetos (**elemento**) que possuem: informações JSON e um objeto (**circulo**) circulo da API do google maps. Quando eu faço uma pesquisa ( recebo um novo JSON), eu acesso **arrayElementos**, e para cada **elemento**, eu acesso o **circulo** e executo a função **circulo.setMap(null)**, porém, o problema é que alguns circulos apagam enquanto outros permanecem. Já fiz debug, mas n consegui identificar o erro.

```
var arrayElementos = [];

function setMapElements(mJsonData) {


    if(arrayElementos.length==0){

        var elementOptions = {
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: {},
            radius: Math.sqrt(1) * 50
        };

        var elemento = {

            idade:{},
            genero:{},
            circulo:{}
        };

        $.each(mJsonData, function(id,data){

            elementOptions.center = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude,data.longitude);

            elemento.genero = data.sexo;
            elemento.idade = data.idade;
            elemento.circulo = new google.maps.Circle(elementOptions);

            mapElements.push(elemento);
        });

    }else{

        $.each(arrayElementos, function(id,elemento){

            elemento.circulo.setMap(null);

        });

        arrayElementos = [];

        setMapElements(mJsonData);
    }

};
```

Comment: Não tenho como testar se minha resposta resolve completamente o seu problema. Próxima vez tente criar uma versão simplificada do seu problema que caiba toda dentro da sua pergunta e não dependa de google maps, vetores globais de json, etc. Se for pequeno o suficiente pra não precisar de barra de rolagem melhor ainda :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está criando um único objeto `elemento` e sobrescrevendo seus campos em cada iteração do loop.

```
 var elemento = {
    idade:{},
    genero:{},
    circulo:{}
};

$.each(mJsonData, function(id,data){

    elementOptions.center = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude,data.longitude);

    elemento.genero = data.sexo;
    elemento.idade = data.idade;
    elemento.circulo = new google.maps.Circle(elementOptions);

    mapElements.push(elemento);
});
```

Ao invés de reutilizar um único elemento, crie um novo a cada passo:

```
$.each(mJsonData, function(id,data){

    elementOptions.center = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude,data.longitude);

    mapElements.push({
        genero : data.sexo,
        idade : data.idade,
        circulo : new google.maps.Circle(elementOptions)
    });
});
```

Um programa mais simples que ilustra o seu bug é esse aqui:

```
var obj = {}
var lista = [];
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    obj.x = i;
    lista[i] = obj;
}
obj.y = 17;
```

Se você imprimir o conteúdo da lista no final, você vai ver que todos os campos apontam pro mesmo objeto.

Comment: Obrigado, não havia percebido este erro!